# more efficient way of looping over name list in python

Tags: python

I"m playing around with [Bittrex's API](https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003723911-Developer-s-Guide-API#general) to get the current price of a coin. (E.g: btc-ltc). So in this case, the API will read:

```
r = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-LTC').json()
pd = pandas.Dataframe(r)
print(pd)
```

If I want to get the current price of maybe... 50 or 200 different coins, i wrote a loop to replace `BTC-LTC` with that particular market coin name. (part of another API on Bittrex)

```
for i in marketnames:
    r = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market={names}'.format(names=i)).json()
    pd = pandas.Dataframe(r)
    print(pd)
```

The problem with this loop is that it goes through 1 by 1, iterating over the list of coin names, 200 times to get the price.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If the API doesn't support it, then it doesn't support it. What can you do?

Answer (score 1):

was there a typo in your code? if you iterate through the marketnames list then you should use i in your code, as below?

```
for i in marketnames:
    r = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market={names}'.format(names=i)).json()
    pd = pandas.Dataframe(r)
    print(pd)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Ben. I must have mistype it!